# How add a list variable in html string?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Currently I am using an html string to create a pdf. In that html string I need to pass a list variable. The problem is I need to create a table using that list variable. But when I try to assign it to a variable inside the script parameter in the html string its not getting assigned.

```
let amountList= [
      { name: 'store Amount', amount: 0 },
      { name: 'reinventAmount', amount: 0 },
      { name: 'Cost Amount', amount: 90 },
      { name: 'Total Amount', amount: 90 }
    ];


let htmlStringUsedforPdf= `<html>
<body>
  <table>
      <thead>
     </thead>
     <tbody class="sub-text" id="testBody"></tbody>
    </table>
  <script>
      
  
    function loadTableData(items) {
      const table = document.getElementById("testBody");
     
    
      items.forEach( item => {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        let name= row.insertCell(0);
        name.innerHTML = item.name;
        let amount= row.insertCell(1);
        amount.innerHTML = item.amount;
      });
    }
    loadTableData(${amountList});
    
  </script>

<body>
</html>`

The table is created without the amountList data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to sort out the problem by stringifying the list. Seems like it was not getting assigned because html was a string.
Solution was

```
amountList = JSON.stringify(amountList)
```

Comment: After having a look at the result, It seems that the problem was that `amountList` was being turned into a string by the usage of `toString` function, and what was passed to `loadTableData` was `[object Object]`, specifically `loadTableData([object Object],[object Object], ...)`. When you've used `JSON.stringify` if correctly stringfied the object.